# How to size a SingleChildScrollView dynamically inside a Column?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm having a bit of a problem with Flutter's widget placement. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: DataTable(
                //Rows and columns filled with random data
                columns: const <DataColumn>[
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Name',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Age',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Role',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Name',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Age',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Role',
                      style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                rows: const <DataRow>[
                  DataRow(
                    cells: <DataCell>[
                      DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                      DataCell(Text('19')),
                      DataCell(Text('Student')),
                      DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                      DataCell(Text('19')),
                      DataCell(Text('Student')),
                    ],
                  ),
                  DataRow(
                    cells: <DataCell>[
                      DataCell(Text('Janine')),
                      DataCell(Text('43')),
                      DataCell(Text('Professor')),
                      DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                      DataCell(Text('19')),
                      DataCell(Text('Student')),
                    ],
                  ),
                  DataRow(
                    cells: <DataCell>[
                      DataCell(Text('William')),
                      DataCell(Text('27')),
                      DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                      DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                      DataCell(Text('19')),
                      DataCell(Text('Student')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            //How to make this widget be at the bottom?
            const Text('This widget should be at the bottom'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a DataTable and a Text widget, wrapped with a Column and two SingleChilScrollViews in order to have bidirectional scrolling (the table is larger than the screen). I want to place the Text widget on the bottom of the screen. Tinkering with the code, I can do it pretty easily by giving the Column widget a parent Container, and fixing its size to my screen. However, how would I go about sizing it dynamically? I've tried using MediaQuery but the result was not that accurate. This "fix" can be found below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                controller: _scrollController,
                child: DataTable(
                  //Rows and columns filled with random data
                  columns: const <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Name',
                        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Age',
                        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Role',
                        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Name',
                        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Age',
                        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Role',
                        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  rows: const <DataRow>[
                    DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                        DataCell(Text('19')),
                        DataCell(Text('Student')),
                        DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                        DataCell(Text('19')),
                        DataCell(Text('Student')),
                      ],
                    ),
                    DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(Text('Janine')),
                        DataCell(Text('43')),
                        DataCell(Text('Professor')),
                        DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                        DataCell(Text('19')),
                        DataCell(Text('Student')),
                      ],
                    ),
                    DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(Text('William')),
                        DataCell(Text('27')),
                        DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                        DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                        DataCell(Text('19')),
                        DataCell(Text('Student')),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              //How to make this widget be at the bottom?
              const Text('This widget should be at the bottom'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to tackle this issue? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Using the text in the bottomNavigationBar of the Scaffold works as well, however it doens't seem an appropriate solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: DataTable(
              //Rows and columns filled with random data
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Name',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Age',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Role',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Name',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Age',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Role',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              rows: const <DataRow>[
                DataRow(
                  cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                    DataCell(Text('19')),
                    DataCell(Text('Student')),
                    DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                    DataCell(Text('19')),
                    DataCell(Text('Student')),
                  ],
                ),
                DataRow(
                  cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(Text('Janine')),
                    DataCell(Text('43')),
                    DataCell(Text('Professor')),
                    DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                    DataCell(Text('19')),
                    DataCell(Text('Student')),
                  ],
                ),
                DataRow(
                  cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(Text('William')),
                    DataCell(Text('27')),
                    DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
                    DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                    DataCell(Text('19')),
                    DataCell(Text('Student')),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const Text('Is at the bottom - doesnt seem right'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a more elegant solution while tinkering with my code and the provided answers. I wrapped the Scaffold's body in a Column and used 2 expanded widgets: one for my bottom widget and another one for the ScrollViews and Table. Here's the final body:

```
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 9,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: _scrollController,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: DataTable(
              columns: _controller.columns,
              rows: _controller.rows,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Total(_controller.total),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

i think This might get you resolved your Error.

Code:

```
Scaffold(
      body:SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-100,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ///// your Scrollabel Data Table will be here
                    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Tile $i'),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Text('Hello I am at the Bottom'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ) ,)
```

Comment: I've tried that however it did not work. The Text widget was close to the Table

Comment: add Column property called mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SingleChildScrollView inside a Listview to achive that.

```
ListView(
 children: [
  SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Column(
     children: [
       //Your table goes here
     ],
    ),
   ),
   Text(
    //Your bottom text goes here,
   ),
  ],
 ),
```

Comment: I've tried that however it did not work. The Text widget was close to the Table

Comment: You could add a space between them using sizedBox like...SizedBox(height: 20)

Answer (score -1):

did you try to use BottomSheetNavigtor?